# How to echo a string and return a value from same function in php

Tags: php, function

I have a situation like this:

```
function getData($key,$value){
   if($key==$value){
     echo 'Key-Value Matched';
       if($value=='foo'){
         $result = 'value is foo';
       }else{
         $result = 'value is bar';
       }
    }
return $result; 
}

 getData('bar','foo');
 echo $result;
 getData('foo','foo'); // Key-Value Matched
 echo $result;
```

As the above code, you can see that I want a echo and a return value from one php function.
But from the execution of the above function, echo part is executing correctly but $result is not coming from that function.
How to achieve both echo and a return value from above function?

Comment: Because you don't assign it. `$result = getData('bar', 'foo');`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You have to learn PHP...

Answer (score 1):

You missed to initialize $result when `$key != $value`. You'll have to add a an else block. Like this:

```
function getData($key,$value){
   if($key==$value){
     echo 'Key-Value Matched';
       if($value=='foo'){
         $result = 'value is foo';
       }else{
         $result = 'value is bar';
       }
    } else {
         $result = 'value is undefined';
    }
    return $result; 
}
```

Also you'll have to store the return value of `getData()` before using it (like @bwoebi mentioned):

```
$result = getData('bar','foo');
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the return value first:

```
 $result = getData('bar','foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a local variable in your function: `$result`, but this `$result` is not your global variable.

You have to make so:

```
echo getdata('bar', 'foo');
echo getData('sss', 'sss');
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData($key,$value){
    if($key===$value){
       echo 'Key-Value Matched';
       if($value=='foo'){
         $result = 'value is foo';
       }else{
         $result = 'value is bar';
       }
       return $result; 
    }else {
       echo 'Key-Value not matched';
    }
}

 echo getData('bar','foo');
 echo getData('foo','foo');
```

- comparing identical-STRINGS must done with "===" for best practices
- Your $result variable is
  limited only for the functions not outside    the functions

Comment: That's not true, you can compare strings with ==

Comment: based on my experience it really matters to use "===" if you really want to compare the exact strings...but yeah you may also use "=="...

Comment: The == operator checks to see if the left and right values are equal. But in this case we know they are two strings. The === operator actually checks to see if the left and right values are equal, and also checks to see if they are of the same variable type (like whether they are both booleans, strings, ints, file types etc etc.). Using an operator when it is not necessary is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

if you REALLY want the `getData` function to update the `$result` variable (I don't recommend it), you could declare it as a global variable inside the function, using the `global` keyword

```
function getData($key, $value){
  global $result;

  if ($key == $value) {
    $result = 'Key-Value Matched';
    if ($value == 'foo') {
      $result = 'value is foo';
    } else {
      $result = 'value is bar';
    }
  }
  return $result; 
}

getData('bar','foo');
echo $result;         // Will print "value is foo"
getData('foo','foo');
echo $result;         // Will print "Key-Value matched"
```

But, once again, you shouldn't do that (your code can get really confusing). You just should use the `getData` return and print it with `echo`.

Answer (score -1):

you shouldn't make a echo in a function. better is to put all the output in a array, and then show it on the browser like this:

```
function getData($key,$value){
   $result = array();
   if($key==$value){
     $result[] = 'Key-Value Matched';
       if($value=='foo'){
         $result[] = 'value is foo';
       }else{
         $result[] = 'value is bar';
       }
    }
return $result; 
}

 $result = getData('bar','foo');
 foreach($result as $entry)
 {
   echo $entry."<br />"
 }
 $result = getData('foo','foo'); // Key-Value Matched
 foreach($result as $entry)
 {
   echo $entry."<br />"
 }
```